# Complex use case about JSR-303, Tapestry, and JPA entity inheritance

Tags: java, jpa, tapestry, bean-validation

I have a JPA entity called `ParentAccount` that extends an abstract `Account` entity (see JPA inheritance). I have place the JSR-303 validation constraints in the Account entity.
Now I have the following Tapestry class and templates and JSR-303 validation does not seem to work:

Tapestry class:

```java
 public class Inscription {        
    @Property
    //this is not validated...
    private ParentAccount parentAccount;

    @Property
    @Validate("required")
    private String accountPasswordConfirmation;    

    @InjectComponent
    private Form registrationForm;

    @OnEvent(EventConstants.PREPARE)
    void prepareAccount(){
        parentAccount = new ParentAccount();
    }

    @OnEvent(value= EventConstants.VALIDATE)
    void validateRegistrationForm() {
        if(registrationForm.isValid()) {
            if(accountPasswordConfirmation.equals(parentAccount.getAccountPassword())) {
                System.out.println("ok for insert");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tapestry page:

```html
<html xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_1_0.xsd">
<head>
    <title>Hello World Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form t:type="form" t:id="registrationForm" validate="this">
    <t:errors/>
    <div>
        <label t:type="label" for="accountEmailAddress"/>
        <input t:type="textfield" t:id="accountEmailAddress" value="parentAccount.accountEmailAddress"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label t:type="label" for="accountFirstName"/>
        <input t:type="textfield" t:id="accountFirstName" value="parentAccount.accountFirstName"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label t:type="label" for="accountLastName"/>
        <input t:type="textfield" t:id="accountLastName" value="parentAccount.accountLastName"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label t:type="label" for="accountPassword"/>
        <input t:type="textfield" t:id="accountPassword" value="parentAccount.accountPassword"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label t:type="label" for="accountPasswordConfirmation"/>
        <input t:type="textfield" t:id="accountPasswordConfirmation" value="accountPasswordConfirmation"/>
    </div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="ok"/></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, even though I have annotated the entity with `@NotNull` annotations, those JSR-303 constraints are ignored.

Can anyone please help?

Regards,

Comment: I noticed that if I add a JSR-303 annotation to a property in the Tapestry class, it does get taken into account. Why then Tapestry won't take into account the annotation when placed upon a property of a JPA entity??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I noticed that if I add a JSR-303 annotation to a property in the Tapestry class, it does get taken into account. Why then Tapestry won't take into account the annotation when placed upon a property of a JPA entity??

In Tapestry a Form is accociated by a [ValidationTracker](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry5.1/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/ValidationTracker.html) that tracks all the provided user input and validation errors for every field in the form.

It seems the default `ValidationTrackerImpl` doesn't care. You could provide your on tracker implementation via the Form's tracker parameter. I did something similiar with Struts2 to have my entities validated.

Maybe (hopefully) annotating your `parentAccount` with `@Valid` (graph validation as it is called in the JSR-303 specification) also works (provided Tapestry cares).

Comment: Thanks. I tried to add a @Valid annotation to the parentAccount property to no avail. I am going to try the other suggested solution and post here accordingly.